# What does inline-block mean for css?

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain the difference between 'block' and 'inline-block' for the CSS display setting?

Comment: If you think about how an image appears in a line of text, you'll get the idea of making an inline-block element.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, it’s a way to make elements inline, but preserving their block capabilities such as setting width and height, top and bottom margins and paddings etc. For example:

[image: Inline-block demo]

(Source: http://www.impressivewebs.com/inline-block/)

Answer (score 5):

inline-block treats the element like other inline elements but allows the use of block properties.

Elements with display: block take up as much width as they are allowed and typically start on a new line.

Comment: Ah, good to know about the 'new line' aspect. `inline-block` is indeed quite nifty.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wonderful detailed article about this topic: [What’s the Deal With Display: Inline-Block?](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for the note, and I will take that into consideration next time.